# colorama/termcolor not returning coloured lines

Tags: colors, colorama

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
print(Back.GREEN + 'and with a green background')
print(Style.DIM + 'and in dim text')
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print('back to normal now')
```

Output

[31msome red text

[42mand with a green background

[2mand in dim text

[0m

back to normal now

I used colorama library to change the font colour of few words. Unfortunately, it is not returning any lines with their respective colors. Can anyone help me to identify the issue?. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your code works on my Linux machine, but if you're on Windows, you have to call `init()` first (as per [documentation](https://github.com/tartley/colorama)). The code looks as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style, init

# only required on Windows
init()

# print some example lines
print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
print(Back.GREEN + 'and with a green background')
print(Style.DIM + 'and in dim text')
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print('back to normal now')
```